# Why do I get an exception for this usage of enable_shared_from_this()?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

On the following example below, something is escaping me. Why does this generate the usual weak_ptr exception when using the shared_from_this, if there is an outstanding shared_ptr reference to the object which calls it ?

```
class A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<A> create() {
        return std::shared_ptr<A>(new A());
    }
    A() {}
    void setParent(const std::shared_ptr<A>& other) {}
    std::shared_ptr<A> keep() {
        auto o = A::create();
        o->setParent(shared_from_this());
        return o;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<A> a = A::create();
    auto s = a->keep();
}
```

Comment: -> `public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to inherit publicly from `enable_shared_from_this` so the shared ptr ctor can see it.

As an aside, clang fails to compile your example due to this.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that was it, although the example compiled ok, and I even stepped debug it to confirm it was being raised by the shared_from_this(). Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin That `shared_from_this` is inaccessible.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont [I don't see this](https://godbolt.org/z/q8EOKk). All I did was add `#include <memory>` and it compiles fine.

Comment: @kevin Probably different version of clang; I used stacked crooked.

Answer (score 2):

`enable_shared_from_this` must be an unambiguous and *accessible* base of `A` for the library to handle the internal weak pointer correctly.

Your inheritance is private (the default when using the `class`  keyword).